# BACK button callback in Overlay window in Android

Tags: android, overlay, keyevent

I'm showing a `overlay window` from service in my app. I want to hide the window when `press back button`. So to get the `back button event` I do the following code

```
class MyView extends MyLayout{
    public MyView(Context context){
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflater(R.layout.my_view,this);
    }
}

Class MyLayout extends FrameLayout{
    public MyLayout(Context context){
       super(context);
    }

   @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        Log.e("key event", "" + event.getKeyCode());
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
//service code
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

final MyView myview = new MyView(this);
windowManager.addView(myview,param);
```

But `dispatchKeyEvent` method never called on `back button pressed`. I Googled and found out this is the way to capture the back button event. Somehow it's not working in my case. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to capture the `back button pressed` event use:

```
@override
public void onBackPressed(){
// Do what you need done here 
// ... or pass super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Real problem is the `window params`. I need to only `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH flags` which prevent other app to `get key events`. So the correct code is following

//service code

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```